# wordpress add_rewrite_rule not working

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have page on my site named annuaire-membres
and i want this with my custom search like this

```
example.com/annuaire-membres/character/A
```

or

```
example.com/annuaire-membres/department/xyz
```

for this I have use the function

```
function md_custom_taxonomies_rewrite(){    
    add_rewrite_tag('%character%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%department%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^annuaire-membres/department/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=27&department=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^annuaire-membres/character/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=27&character=$matches[1]','top');   
}
add_action('init','md_custom_taxonomies_rewrite');
```

but this is not working
any buddy pla help me to solve this

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? what happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: if i entered this url example.com/annuaire-membres/department/xyz then it comes on 404 page not found.i want to go on my page like this example.com/annuaire-membres/?department=xyz

Comment: Have you flushed rewrite rules after adding this code?

Comment: not yet. if i do the same,will it create any problem?

Comment: i have also try flushed rewrite rules but still same results.
/* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'md_flush_rewrite_rules' );

/* Flush your rewrite rules */
function md_flush_rewrite_rules() {
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}

Comment: `after_switch_theme` only runs if you switch to a different theme and switch back to yours. just visit the permalinks settings page to flush rewrites.

Comment: dude, can plz tell me how to do it :)

Comment: Just go to `settings > permalinks` in admin, that's it

Comment: nothing happen if i plcae  flush_rewrite_rules() in  md_custom_taxonomies_rewrite() this function same 404 page error